# PayPal webhook custom headers

Tags: paypal, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I need to add custom headers to my PayPal webhook calls, so I can make a message in Slack. Is there any way to add headers to a PayPal webhook request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in webhook creation that would let you set a custom header for PayPal to send along with the webhook: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#webhooks_post

So, the straightforward solution would be to have the webhook go to your own code/listener, and that webhook listener of yours can immediately do a Slack API call to send the message.

Comment: How would I create a listener?

Comment: Uhm, start by having a web server somewhere with a publicly accessible URL endpoint, then write and place a script there that listens for Webhook calls from PayPal.  When it receives one, it does an API call to Slack to to create the message you desire.